# How can I increase the accuracy of predicting the occurrence of event using logistic regression?

Tags: logistic

I will work on climate data to predict if a disease it will happen or not on a crop. During search I found logistic regression is best choice for my research, but it has several problems led to reduce the prediction. I'm new to prediction analysis and I don't know how to increase my prediction accuracy. There are several selection methods used with it. Which one is best to select data to fit the model. Which type of regression help me in this research?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Enas. I tried to edit your question to make it clearer. However, I still do not quite follow your question. For example, we do not "select data to fit the model"; did you mean how to select *variables*? See if you can clarify your question further so that people will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

You don't select data to fit the model ordinarily; you select a model that is *likely* to fit the data.  Have you read some standard texts on logistic regression?  What do you mean by 'reduce the prediction'?  Note that use of proportion classified correctly in this context will be very misleading, e.g., there are cases in which you get a higher classification accuracy by discarding all the covariate data.

Comment: thanks for  you , 'reduce the prediction' I mean problems related with logistic regression such as multicolinerity problem and other .

Comment: collinearity won't effect the prediction of the model, only the estimates of the coefficients for the variables involved. For a binary classification issue, logistic models are the gold-standard. And a good base to build on. You can then expand/change you approach as your understanding of the data improves.